# Conditional probability for Markov model

Tags: python

My data set consists of daily rainfall records for 31 days (zero represents no rain and non-zero entry represents rain). I required to compute the conditional probability in 4 different cases as explained below:

1. rainy day .... rainy day
2. rainy day ... non-rainy day
3. non-rainy day ...  rainy-day
4. non-rainy day ... non-rainy-day

May someone suggest to me how to compute the conditional probabilities for the above-mentioned cases.

The data set and sample script are as below:

```
import numpy as np # Processing Array
import scipy.stats # Computing Statistic
import scipy.linalg # Linear Algebra
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Drawing Graph

C_prep = np.array( [0.00, 0.04, 0.84, 0.00, 0.00, 
                    0.00, 0.02, 0.05, 0.01, 0.09,
                    0.18, 0.04, 0.04, 0.00, 0.06,
                    0.03, 0.04, 0.00, 0.00, 0.33,
                    0.02, 0.01, 0.33, 0.08, 0.00,
                    0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.01, 0.01,
                    0.13])
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a loop and counting how many times a non-zero value follows a zero value, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution you want:
Please note that `transitions` can be a just a simple list; no need for numpy array.

```
transitions = [0.00, 0.04, 0.84, 0.00, 0.00,
               0.00, 0.02, 0.05, 0.01, 0.09,
               0.18, 0.04, 0.04, 0.00, 0.06,
               0.03, 0.04, 0.00, 0.00, 0.33,
               0.02, 0.01, 0.33, 0.08, 0.00,
               0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.01, 0.01,
               0.13]

# first create the 2 states of interest
transitions = [1 if x > 0 else 0 for x in transitions]

n = 1 + max(transitions)  # number of states

M = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)] # create matrix for probabilities

for (i, j) in zip(transitions, transitions[1:]):
    M[i][j] += 1

# now convert to probabilities:
for row in M:
    s = sum(row)
    if s > 0:
        row[:] = [f / s for f in row]
        
print(M)
>>> [[0.5454545454545454, 0.45454545454545453], 
     [0.21052631578947367, 0.7894736842105263]]
```

Each cells represents a conditional probability,i.e. transition probability:  a) no-rain -> no-rain, etc.

Comment: Thank you ... your script is very useful for me ...

Answer (score 0):

This loops through the list and checks.

```py
import numpy as np
C_prep = np.array( [0.00, 0.04, 0.84, 0.00, 0.00, 
                    0.00, 0.02, 0.05, 0.01, 0.09,
                    0.18, 0.04, 0.04, 0.00, 0.06,
                    0.03, 0.04, 0.00, 0.00, 0.33,
                    0.02, 0.01, 0.33, 0.08, 0.00,
                    0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.01, 0.01,
                    0.13])
sit1 = 0; sit2 = 0; sit3 = 0; sit4 = 0 #situations 1,2,3,4
'''
sit1 is rainy day .... rainy day
sit2 is rainy day ... non-rainy day
sit3 is non-rainy day ... rainy-day
sit4 is non-rainy day ... non-rainy-day
'''
for c, v in enumerate(C_prep):
    if c == len(C_prep) - 1: 
        break
    next_val = C_prep[c+1]
    '''now check for all the four possible solutions, i.e. if num is 0 and if the 
    next num is 0'''
    if v == float(0) and next_val == float(0):
        sit1 += 1
    elif v == float(0) and next_val != float(0):
        sit2 += 1
    elif v != float(0) and next_val == float(0):
        sit3 += 1
    elif v != float(0) and next_val != float(0):
        sit4 += 1
print(sit1, sit2, sit3, sit4)
```